# Can't find OCaml module FileInfo when compiling parts of Hack

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I'm trying to compile parts of the Hack compiler, specifically the parser/lexer/ast part, but the module FileInfo is missing. Is it made in C? How would I include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard, filename was `fileInfo.ml`, not `fileinfo.ml`.